# MVC-How to tell the mainview (which contains the PartialView) when the event fires in PartialView?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, ztree

My mainview contains a PartialView and a function called `FinishedSelectInMain()`,and the PartialView is a ztree which has check event and click event and used in many pages.Now  when I click the  ztree in PartialView,How can I call the  `FinishedSelectInMain()` funcion after the click function in PartialView ?I know in the PartialView it will execute click function automatically when I click the ztree. I know that put the `FinishedSelectInMain()` function after click funcion in the PartialView will be OK,But it will destroy the integrity of the PartialView.Because the `FinishedSelectInMain()` function is only for the mainpage,but the PartialView is not only used in the mainpage,it is also used in page1,page2.

Answer (score 0):

do fire events off of the partial view you need to put your code on the main page and tie it to the document

```
$(document).on('click', '.ClassOnPartial', function(){
    FinishedSelectInMain()
});
```

with this code on the main page it will trigger when a an input on your partial with class "ClassOnPartial" is clicked.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you,it work well.If I click the tree,it will fire the click event in partial view and then execute the FinishedSelectInMain.But if I want to execute the funcion in the mainpage first and the execute the click event in the partial view?How to change it?It seems to  work bad.  
`$(document).on('beforeclick', '.ClassOnPartial', function(){
    BeforeSelectInMain()
});`

Comment: if you want to fire the function on the when the page loads I would just put the function call into $(document).ready(function(){...